# RJDBC too slow to read SQL Server table

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc, r-dbi, rjdbc

I am using RJDBC package to connect R to SQL server. But when I am trying to read input from tables, it is taking a lot of time foe reading. Below is the snippet which will give you the idea, how am I trying to access tables.

```
LocationOfJDBC <- "local_path/sqljdbc41.jar"
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8048m")
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" ,LocationOfJDBC ,identifier.quote="`")

mydb <- dbConnect(drv, paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://",DBhost,";databaseName=",DBname), DBuser, DBpass)

#dbListTables(mydb)
#dbDisconnect(mydb)

# Reading SQL Table using DBSENDQUERY Method-which is taking almost 2.6 mins for 100k rows and 14 columns (7 varchar,7 int)
Qyery1<-paste("select * from table1 where id = ",user_id,sep="")
R_table1 = dbSendQuery(mydb, Qyery1)
R_df_table1 = fetch (R_table1, n=-1)

# Reading SQL Table using DBGETQUERY Method - which is taking almost 140 sec for 100k rows and 14 columns (7 varchar,7 int)
Qyery1 <- paste("select * from table1 where id = ",user_id,sep="")
R_df_table1 = dbGetQuery(mydb, Qyery1)
```

Is there a better way to do it. There are other clients which are taking less than 10 sec. Why is R so slow?

Comment: `too slow` is too vague. How mach data is there? Is `ID` covered by an index? What is the table schema, what indexes are there, what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Have you tried executing the same query in SSMS or Azure Data Studio? If the query is still slow, the problem is probably caused by missing indexes. If it's faster, it's probably due to the driver or JDBC. You could use SQL Server's own [ODBC driver for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) with RODBC

Comment: The edid didn't add any relevant information. If `ID` isn't indexed, the database will have to scan every row to find matches.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos ID column is the primary key of the table. I can't share the exact schema here and I am sorry, I don't have information of index.

Comment: @kawlseo then people can't answer the question. Have you tried executing the query with another client tool like ADS or SSMS? Right now you don't even know if it's the query or the driver at fault. Both SSMS and ADS can show you the execution plan of a query. If you see a table scan you'll know the query isn't using any indexes.

Comment: Its not the query, I have already written it in my question. there are people in my team who have tried executing the same query from other clients and it is taking less than 10 sec

Comment: 100K rows is almost no data. Try using [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017) or [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017). Is the query still slow? It could be your network connection, it could be the switch you connect to, it could be the JDBC driver you use is too slow - after all, it's always going to be *slower* than a native driver.

Comment: `there are people in my team` that doesn't say much. Had the tried the same thing, with the same environment, they'd have gotten the same results. You'll have to isolate what's different.

Comment: BTW [the lastest SQL Server JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017) is 7.0, not 4.1. The performance difference may be due to the outdated driver

Comment: I get your "100K rows is almost no data" part but I am not sure about the other things. Also, when I use the same query for certain IDs where data is less (~ 5k rows), code is taking less than 10 sec in the same system/local machine.

Comment: `for certain IDs where data is less` ??? A Primary key is *unique*. If you have multiple rows for the same ID it means it's not a primary key and probably isn't indexed at all

Comment: Are you using RStudio to connect? What happens at command line with Rscript?

Comment: Yes, I am using Rstudio and command line gets stuck at fetch statement till the time data is completely fetched from SQL Server.